# How to add a new language to an existing netbeans project suite?

Tags: netbeans, internationalization, resourcebundle, netbeans-platform

I have a project suite in netbeans for a desktop app.

It supports English and Spanish, and all via bundle.properties files in each package.

Now we have to add a new language and I'm looking for a quick way to extract all the bundles, translate them to the new language, and put them back to their appropriate place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, but it's not very fast solution. I found that extracting the bundles and use a different tool (in this case I used crowdin.com), is much faster

Answer (score 1):

click your module, tools -> internatialization and this is all.

Jirka

Comment: Thanks, but it's not very fast solution. I found that extracting the bundles and use a different tool (in this case I used crowin.com), is much faster